# Importing Objective-c framework in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to import a library of objective-c into swift. I've created a bridging file (a .h) and added it to the build settings, in Objective-C Bridging Header under Swift Compiler - General. Into the bridging file I've added `#import <MyFramework>`.

The problem comes now. This framework is private and particular. To install it correctly in Objective-C they told you to change the main.m to main.mm (which don't have sense in swift).

When I try to build the project I get 111 errors (Apple Mach-O linker error). It start with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

And all the errors are similar to:

```
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__grow_by(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
```

So I really don't understand it. Do you have any clue why is this happening?

If you need me to post some more information just tell me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @macroland I don't think so. I've used it in another project, in objective-C, and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.mm extension is used for using c++ code .. std :: is c++ code. you just need to edit yourBridgingHeaderFile.m   to YourBridingHeaderName.mm and you would be good to go

[image: .mm file]

Comment: Ook, I was really lost on this. It work! Thanks for the help.

Comment: i am Glad that i helped :)